# how to launch specific activity when nfc detect tag?

Tags: android, nfc

Currently I am working with nfc reader. In this application nfc read tags and redirect to specific activity. But I want to redirect when user in background or app in kill state.

my manifest file

```
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="in.adsmn.nfsreader">
   <uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />

<application
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Activity.Event_Executed"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activity.VideoViewActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
    <activity
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:name=".Activity.Tech_Activation_Activity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
    <activity android:name=".Activity.MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />

        </intent-filter>
        <!-- no need to use this when user to open deafualt app-->
      <!--  <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
            android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />-->
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Activity.ViewPaigerClass"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"></activity>
</application>
```

I have all  ready tried some answer from stack overflow but none of them worked, So please  tell me some thing that what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance

Comment: i am using         <data android:mimeType=" application/in.adsmn.nfsreader.tech" />  in manifest..please help me if there is anything i am doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

You need to use deeplink for launching a specific Activity or Fragment.

And make your activity `android:launchMode="singleTop"`

Here is [the reference](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking) for how to make deeplink.

For the fragment, you'd better to check [Navigation Component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started).